# error: Failed to attach device from error: internal error: No more available PCI slots

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt, pci

**Assumptions**

- Guest VM has been installed.
- Guest VM is running: `virsh start <vm_domain_name>`.
- Verify it with `virsh list --all`
- Target PCI devices have been detached from the host with `virsh nodedev-detach <pci_<domain>_<bus>_<slot>_<function>>`. One can see a list of PCI targets by verifying the output of `virsh nodedev-list`. One can see that the tag format (<pci__>) may differ from the example here.

**Problem Description**

```
error: Failed to attach device from add_pci_vf.xml
error: internal error: No more available PCI slots
```

This error appears when trying to add multiple PCI devices to a guest virtual machine.

If one just needs to add a single PCI device, then the following command suffice to enable its PCI passthrough:

`virsh attach-device ubuntu-guest add_pci_vf.xml --live`

The option `--live` at the end of the command allows the PCI passthrough to be effective immediately. Access the guest and run `lspci -nn` to assert that the device can now be seen by the guest.

**Solution**

If one wish to add additional devices, one must replace `--live` by `--config`. The changes will not be effective immediately. Follow the recipe below to add multiple PCI devices and avoid the aforementioned error.

```
virsh attach-device <vm_domain_name> <pci_device_0.xml> --config
virsh attach-device <vm_domain_name> <pci_device_1.xml> --config
virsh attach-device <vm_domain_name> <pci_device_2.xml> --config
virsh destroy <vm_domain_name>
virsh start <vm_domain_name>
```

The syntax of pci_device_?.xml files should look like the following (may vary depending on the target co-processor):

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<driver name='vfio' />
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x6b' slot='0x00' function='0x01' />
</source>
</hostdev>
```

> Note: The attribute managed='yes' is essential as per my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in the original post worked for me. Since I had trouble finding it online, I am posting it here for others facing similar issues.

**Summary**

Add the devices (VFs) one by one.

```
virsh attach-device <vm_domain_name> <pci_device_0.xml> --config
virsh attach-device <vm_domain_name> <pci_device_1.xml> --config
virsh attach-device <vm_domain_name> <pci_device_2.xml> --config
```

Then,

```
virsh destroy <vm_domain_name>
virsh start <vm_domain_name>
```

The syntax of pci_device_?.xml files is similar to:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<driver name='vfio' />
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x6b' slot='0x00' function='0x01' />
</source>
</hostdev>
```